# Is there a way to iterate an HTMLCollectionOf<Element> array?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm doing a chrome extension trying to reach a list of prices from a marketplace.

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8UXv.png)

I actually found the way to retrieve the elements from the website using this.

const pricesArray = document.getElementsByClassName('css-1eegk7w');
[pricesArray content at console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K69VM.png)

One thing is that If I do console.log(pricesArray.lenght) it shows 0.

Also I can't fit it at any way of iterating this type of object.

I was expecting to make a list containing the .innerText from each element that I found from the website.

[console log debug img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4iXn.png)

Comment: `console.log(pricesArray.lenght)` - should give you an error as you've spelled "length" incorrectly.

Comment: It was only at the post, not at the code.